# Generic rest parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts generic rest parameters:

```
function fn<T>(...args: T[]): Something<T> {
}

let something = fn(1, 2, 3, 4);  // all good.
```

I would optionally like to be able to call this function with an array parameter, without using the spread operator (it makes chaining things much clearer):

```
let something = fn([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Passing an array makes the return type `Something<T[]>`, which makes sense with the current type signature, but I would really like the return type to be `Something<T>` instead.

```
let something: Something<number> = fn([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

I really want a type that is something like:

```
(arg T) | (...args T[])
```

I just can't work out the incantation.

Comment: you could spread the input array? so call it like `fn(...[1,2,3,4])` and it works like before.

Comment: It seems like you want two signatures, `(arg: T[]) => Something<T>` _or_ `(...args: T[]) => Something<T>`, in which case https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: @Plagiatus I know I can do that, but it makes the code quite messy.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't get that working. I think it is because overloading requires different function arity and rest parameters count as a single argument.

Comment: It's not clear what specific problem you've had. Note that one downside of all of this is it's ambiguous what should happen in cases where there's a single array argument - is T the _content_ of the array, or the array itself? The implementation won't have access to the type metadata, so e.g. `thing<number[]>([1, 2, 3])` will compile as returning `Something<number[]>` but you'd probably get `Something<number>` at runtime.

Comment: You're right, the implementation is actually fine. 
It's really a minor thing. I just want to get rid of the spread operator for the array case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function overloading:

```
function fn<T>(args: T[]): Something<T>
function fn<T>(...args: T[]): Something<T>
function fn<T>(...args: ([T[]]) | T[]): Something<T> {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Genius! The `([T[]]) | T[])` is the magic I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to define different signatures to your function

```
type Fn<T> = {
  (...params: T[]): Something<T>;
  (params: T[]): Something<T>;
};

const fn: Fn<number> => (...params) => {
  ...
};
```

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Is there a way of making the function implementation generic?

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: You solution requires creating a function implementation for every expected T, and doesn't quite resolve the issue.